# How to create navigation and footer file separately and then add to the all pages of websites in core php?

Tags: php, html

i just want to learn how to add navigation and footer seperatly so it can be used on every page.
I know this thing that in php we can create a footer and naivgation file seperatly and then on every page we can use it like include "navigation.php";
but i want to learn in which file we use html tags and in  which page we use just use code of that particular page only. if you have any links where i can learn this  its helpful.

Comment: I recommend you the Laracast series for PHP begginers, it's really useful - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dda0u9I2mog

Comment: Please note that asking us for tutorial recommendations or similar, is explicitly considered off-topic here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

First, you create index.php this is your main file that will the customer see when came to your site. Then you do header.php , navigation.php, and footer.php. Call all this with include inside index file. It's that easy.